# How to sort a two dimensional string array and assign it to a label

Tags: c#, arrays

```
new List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < contentList.Count; i++) //contentList is a list which can have many rows of data...
{
    string str1 = contentList[i].Quicklink; // Get data 1
    string str2 = contentList[i].Title; // Get data 2
    list.Add(new[] { str1, str2 });
}

//SORT THE LIST based by `str2`

for (int p = 0; p < list.Count; p++)
{
    Label1.Text += str1 + " " + str2 "\r\n";;
}
```

How can I sort the list based on the `str2` value and then assign key pair values to a label.

Comment: `list.OrderBy(x => x[1])`? But if you only and always have two, then a `List<Tuple<String, String>>` might make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you have linq:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(item => item[1]);
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach(var item in sorted)
    Label1.Text += item[0] + " " + item[1] + "\r\n"; //forgot the "+"
```

Comment: Short and simple. Thank you.

Comment: Same comment applies here: Don't loop appending text to a `Control.Text` property. Every iteration will send a windows message!

Comment: ... yes, in a real program I would use a StreamBuilder, this is just a correction to the user's example.

Comment: Or you could even using something like `Label1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", list.OrderBy(item => item[1]).Select(item => string.Join(" ", item)));`

Comment: that's a lot worse than an stringbuilder as it uses strings and each join will create a new one, am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong. ;) It uses the overload of `string.Join()` which takes an `IEnumerable<string>`, which is very efficient.

Comment: Actually, using a StringBuilder for the whole thing would probably be slightly more efficient, so you're correct really. :)

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption that you *don't* really need the `list` for any other purpose, we can just do this in one loop by iterating over the `contentList` in the order that we want (this approach has a benefit of being more obvious about how we are sorting the data).

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in contentList.OrderBy(x => x.Title))
{
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0} {1}\r\n", c.QuickLink, c.Title));
}
Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Note: updated with `StringBuilder` implementation and only one assignment to `Label1.Text`.

Comment: I would avoid repeatedly updating a UI element like that.

Comment: Well, a better way would be to use `StringBuilder` and then just assign `Label1.Text` after the loop, but this is simpler to type and it gets the point across.

Comment: The OP might just copy your code though, so best to warn them not to do it like that. Look at [the implementation of the setter for Control.Text](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a).

Comment: @MatthewWatson updated to use `StringBuilder` and single assignment to Label :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use LINQ:

```
list.OrderBy(arr => arr[1]).ToList()
```

Sorry, couldn't test it as I am answering from my cellphone.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sring.Concat and it has one overload which accepts IEnumerable

```
var sorted = from l in list.OrderBy(item => item[1])
             select l[0]+" "+l[1]+"\r\n";

Label1.Text = string.Concat(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var content in contentList.OrderBy(p=>p.Title)) {
        sb.Append(content.Quicklink);
        sb.Append(" ");
        sb.Append(content.Title);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);


    }

    Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

**Note:** The String Builder is handy because of the fact that strings are immutable and carelessly using `+` operator on strings creates a new string every time. The String Builder prevents this from happening.